# Unable to find version 3.0.0 of package bootstrap when adding a view in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am working on VS 2017 MVC. When I am trying to add a view I am getting the error

**There was an error running the selected code generator: Unable to find version 3.0.0 of package bootstrap.**

Here is a [screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8VcS.png)

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution yourself? What have you tried. Other people asked similar questions, for example here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f99fd46a-3428-4806-8737-902bd6ee34fb/unable-to-find-version-300-of-package-bootstrap?forum=Offtopic

Comment: **NB:** [Bootstrap v3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/3.0.0) "has at least one vulnerability with moderate severity".

Answer (score 0):

To Install Package in Offline:
Step 1: Go to Tools NuGet Package Managermanage Nuget package solution.

Step 2: In there you can see pack source click on setting icon.

Step3: After the setting icon you can see name and source
Enter the url path correctly https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json then click ok.